# Creating a class and adding methods dynamically in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, datamapper

How do I go about creating a new class and adding a few methods to it without resorting to "eval"?

Here's what I'm trying to do; I'd like to transform this structure:

```
obj = [
{
    :scope => 'account',
    :fields => [
        { :title => 'title', :length => 64, :required => true   },
        { :title => 'email', :length => 256, :required => true, :type => 'email'    }
    ],
    :before_save => Proc.new{
        #do something here
    },
},

{
    :scope => 'product',
    :fields => [
        { :title => 'title', :length => 64, :required => true   },
        { :title => 'description', :length => 256, :required => true    },
        { :title => 'cost', :required => true, :type => 'decimal'   }
    ]
    },
]
```

into this:

```
class Account
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,       Serial
    property :title,    String, :length => 64, :required => true
    property :email,    String, :length => 256, :required => true

    def before_save
        #do something here
    end
end
```

...

Thanks!

Comment: More details would be helpful. There are a few different ways to go about this.

Comment: Doing some research into Ruby metaprogramming should show you that there's a lot you can do without having to resort to `eval`ing stuff.

Comment: I skimmed through "Metaprogramming Ruby" but couldn't get an immediate answer and thus this post. I agree I need to spend more time reading it to fully grasp the ideas therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew already said, there are different ways to create class dynamically. This could be one of them:

Say you start with one DM model (haven't used DM, taking the first one from the docs):

```
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,         Serial    # An auto-increment integer key
  property :title,      String    # A varchar type string, for short strings
  property :body,       Text      # A text block, for longer string data.
  property :created_at, DateTime  # A DateTime, for any date you might like.
end
```

and you want to create it dynamically, from a metadata given in a hash of the form

```
{:ClassName => {:field1 => :Type1, :field2 => :Type2 ...}}
```

You could do:

```
require 'data_mapper'

models = {:Post => {
  :id => :Serial,
  :title => :String,
  :body => :Text
}}

models.each do |name, fields|
  klass = Class.new do
    include DataMapper::Resource

    fields.each do |field_name, field_type|
      property(field_name, const_get(field_type))
    end
  end
  Object.const_set(name, klass)
end
```

Key methods:

- [`Class.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-c-new)
- [`Module#const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_set)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look at a real-world example, please consult the code in this library: https://github.com/apohllo/rod/blob/v0.7.x/lib/rod/model.rb#L410